# Why is $f(T)x=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint f(z)(z-T)^{-1}x \ dz$?

Tags: functional-analysis, functional-calculus

Let $T$ be an element of $B(X)$, $f$ be analytic in a neighbourhood of the $T$'s spectrum.

Why do we have the following

$$f(T)x=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint f(z)(z-T)^{-1}x \ dz \text{ ?}$$

I would think we could only say that $f(T)x=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint f(z)(z-T)^{-1} \ dz\ x$.

Is it because we know that $(f\circ g) (T)=f(g(T))$?

$$f(T)(x)=f(T(x))=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint f(z)(z-T(x))^{-1} \ dz=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint f(z)(z-T)^{-1}(x) \ dz$$

I'm learning by myself, so it's not easy to understand what type of context is helpful for this question.
I'm reading the book  Functional Analysis by Joseph Muscat.

Comment: In your last line, $f(T(x))$ doesn't make sense, and neither does what comes after.

Comment: @Aweygan I would really appreciate if you could tell me why it doesn't make sense. I'm learning this by myself. Thanks